# "-pix_fmt p010le" and "-pix_fmt yuv420p10le" doesn't work on FFMpeg hevc_nvenc

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, nvidia, nvenc

This command line works fine:

```
$ ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input_video.mkv -vf scale_cuda=720:404 -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset p7 -rc vbr -rc-lookahead 20 -b:v 2000k -bufsize 5M -maxrate 2000k -g 250 -an -sn output_video.mkv
```

But if I add `-pix_fmt p010le` or `-pix_fmt yuv420p10le` options I get errors:

```
$ ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input_video.mkv -vf scale_cuda=720:404 -pix_fmt p010le -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset p7 -rc vbr -rc-lookahead 20 -b:v 2000k -bufsize 5M -maxrate 2000k -g 250 -an -sn output_video.mkv

Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_scale_cuda_0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
[vf#0:0 @ 0x5581947ccbc0] Error reinitializing filters!
[vf#0:0 @ 0x5581947ccbc0] Task finished with error code: -38 (Function not implemented)
[vf#0:0 @ 0x5581947ccbc0] Terminating thread with return code -38 (Function not implemented)
[vost#0:0/hevc_nvenc @ 0x55819487d080] Could not open encoder before EOF
[vost#0:0/hevc_nvenc @ 0x55819487d080] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
[vost#0:0/hevc_nvenc @ 0x55819487d080] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)
[out#0/matroska @ 0x558194c633c0] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
```

I use *FFMpeg version N-114081-g64634e809f-20240310* (Linux) and my NVIDIA graphic card is *GeForce GTX 1050 Ti*.

Comment: The issue that `hevc_nvenc` uses pixel format `cuda`, and we can't use `-pix_fmt p010le`. Try `scale_cuda=720:404:format=p010le` and `-profile:v main10`: `ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input.mkv -vf scale_cuda=720:404:format=p010le -c:v hevc_nvenc -profile:v main10 -preset p7 -rc vbr -rc-lookahead 20 -b:v 2000k -bufsize 5M -maxrate 2000k -g 250 -an -sn output_video.mkv`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks you very much, my friend @Rotem